# Stress and intonation in "I'm proud of you"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, accent

When I pronounce the phrase: "I'm proud of you" to communicate that I'm proud of the person I'm talking to, do I only need to stress the word "proud" a bit?

I think that stressing the pronouns "I" and "you" are only needed when we want to make contrast between people, but it's probably less common. Am I right? The common stress pattern I think is something like: da-DA-da-da.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to emphasize is the fact that you're proud, then yes, stress the word "proud" a little. Like you said in the second paragraph, if your intention is to distinguish between the people involved, stress the "I" and "you".

Comment: Thank you. My phrase phonetically looks like: [aɪm ˈpraʊ_dəv yʊ]. The word "proud" and "of" are linked. But I noticed that "of" can be pronounced two ways in the dictionary: "əv" and "ə". Do Americans usually drop that "v"? In other words do they spell it like:  [aɪm ˈpraʊ_də yʊ] ?

Comment: Americans don't *usually* drop the "v" sound but it's not unknown to hear "I'm prouda you!"